# .NET 4.5 breaks static bindings

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

This code works in 4.0 but throws `ApplicationException: Binding.StaticSource cannot be set while using Binding.Source.` in 4.5:

```
public class Test
{
    public static string Prop { get; set; }
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var binding = new Binding
    {
        Source = typeof(Test),
        Path = new PropertyPath(typeof(Test).GetProperty("Prop")),
        Mode = BindingMode.OneWayToSource,
        UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
    };
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(textBox1, TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
}
```

Is there a workaround? The goal is to programmatically bind to static property (OneWayToSource) without instantiating `Test`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `Source` property in `static bindings`. This won't even run in .Net 4.0 either. Remove `Source` property and it will -

```
var binding = new Binding
{
    Path = new PropertyPath(typeof(Test).GetProperty("Prop")),
    Mode = BindingMode.OneWayToSource,
    UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
};
BindingOperations.SetBinding(textBox1, TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
```